# Does tvOS 9.2 allow 3rd party apps access to Siri Search API?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, siri

If so, where can I find the documentation? I've search all over apple developer center and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Update: I heard they only allow some developers to do this. Looks like you need a special contract with Apple.

Comment: Any documentation to support the fact that you need a contract with Apple to make your app part of Universal Search?

Answer (score 1):

at the moment not. the only way I could think of would be siri searching the web and having a site wich redirects to your app, but that also would not work on tvos, since siri there just searches media at the moment...

Comment: I remember Apple said they will open the Siri search API to public with 9.2 :(